# How to Read Bytes and Change It into Integers in .*scm file

Tags: python, binary

I am trying to read the data which is related to "face mesh" and "texture mesh" information.

Following is the explanation of the data-set and the next grey box represents how I look when I open up this `*.scm` file with my Sublime text editor.

I merely guess each line contains 4 bytes(4 * 8bits), but as long as I know bit represents 0 or 1, but there we have like `bc06`, where `b,c,6` are not binary.

It looks like I didn't know fundamental basics about how datas are represented.

And also, I didn't know what little-endianess.

Where should I start from?

I know python and I can deal with it pretty well but it was just autodidactic and never learn CS in a regular way.

Appreciate your help in advance.

> **Shape and Texture Models (*.scm)**
>
> The shape model describes the statistical variation of vertex positions, i.e., variations in their x, y and z coordinates, around the mean position. Equally, the texture model describes the variation of vertex colours (red, green and blue).
>   To this purpose the face shape and texture are vectorised. A shape vector describes the x, y and z coordinates of all N vertices in sequence: [x1, y1, z1, . . . , xN , yN , zN ]. And the texture vector follows: [r1,g1,b1,...,rN,gN,bN].
>   The layout of an *.scm file is as follows (little-endian byte order). Note that an unsigned int is 4 bytes and a double is 8 bytes.
>
> 1. unsigned int: the number of vertices: N
> 2. unsigned int: the number of triangles: M
> 3. 3M unsigned ints: the triangles as triplets of vertex indices. 4. The shape PCA model:
>      (a) unsigned int: the number of components: S
>      (b) unsigned int: the length of a basis vector: D = 3N
>      (c) SD doubles: the matrix of principal components as S sequences of D vectors in order. Each vector is in the format defined above.
>      (d) unsigned int: the length of a basis vector, again (D).
>      (e) D doubles: the mean shape vector in the format defined above.
>      (f) unsigned int: the number of eigenvalues (should sensibly be S).
>      1
>      (g) S doubles: the eigenvalues in the order matching the principal components.

```
    bc06 0000 280d 0000 5801 0000 5a01 0000
    4d03 0000 5801 0000 4d03 0000 5901 0000
    5c01 0000 5901 0000 4d03 0000 5c01 0000
    4d03 0000 5a01 0000 f902 0000 fa02 0000
    4e03 0000 f902 0000 4e03 0000 fb02 0000
    fd02 0000 fb02 0000 4e03 0000 fd02 0000
    4e03 0000 fa02 0000 5b01 0000 6101 0000
    4f03 0000 5b01 0000 4f03 0000 1801 0000
    1901 0000 1801 0000 4f03 0000 1901 0000
    4f03 0000 6101 0000 fc02 0000 c202 0000
    5003 0000 fc02 0000 5003 0000 0203 0000
    c302 0000 0203 0000 5003 0000 c302 0000
    5003 0000 c202 0000 5901 0000 5501 0000
    5103 0000 5901 0000 5103 0000 5801 0000
    5d01 0000 5801 0000 5103 0000 5d01 0000
    5103 0000 5501 0000 fa02 0000 f902 0000
    5203 0000 fa02 0000 5203 0000 f602 0000
    fe02 0000 f602 0000 5203 0000 fe02 0000
    5203 0000 f902 0000 5501 0000 5901 0000
    5303 0000 5501 0000 5303 0000 5601 0000
    5b01 0000 5601 0000 5303 0000 5b01 0000
    5303 0000 5901 0000 f602 0000 f702 0000
    5403 0000 f602 0000 5403 0000 fa02 0000
    fc02 0000 fa02 0000 5403 0000 fc02 0000
```

**+ additional question: Why does it have 0000 for every line after hexdecimal?**

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams when I use unpack() in python, which format should I use? I had done following : from struct import* //scm = open("/Users/zachary/Downloads/sfm_shape_1724.scm")//unpack(scm) returns error requiring fmt to denote.